# What is the least resource intensive to perform "findManyOrCreate" in Laravel eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have an array of post codes coming from an input:

```
$postCodes = collect(["BK13TV", "BK14TV", "BK15TV", "BK16TV"]);
```

In my database I already have two of the post codes - "BK13TV", "BK16TV".

So I would like to run something like this:

```
$postCodeModels = PostCode::findManyOrCreate($postCodes->map($postCode) {
 return ['code' => $postCode]
})
```

My initial approach was to load all the post codes, then diff them against the postCodes from the input like so:

```
PostCode::createMany($postCodes->diff(PostCode::all()->pluck('code')))
```

However, here it means that I am loading the entire content of post_codes table, which just seems wrong.

In the ideal case, this would return all post code models matching the passed post codes as well as would create entries for post codes that did not exist in the database.

Comment: You don't have to fetch the whole table: `PostCode::distinct()->pluck('code')`

Comment: All post codes are distinct in my case.

Comment: You can achieve this with a single UPSERT query, I've created a package for that: https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-upsert However, the package does not return model instances. You could use `PostCode::hydrate()` for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I need to retrieve existing postcodes:

```
$existingPostCodes = PostCode::whereIn('code', $postCodes)->get();
```

The find all the post codes in the input, that are not stored yet in database:

```
$newPostCodes = $postCodes->diff($existingPostCode->pluck('code'));
```

Finally retrieve all the new post codes as models:

```
$postCodeModels = PostCode::whereIn('code', $postCodes)->get();
```

Admittedly, this still takes three queries, but does eliminate the crazy stuff of loading an entire table worth of data.